# Button variable not recognized within OnClick Listener

Tags: java, android, xml

I am quite new to Android, and this is the first project I've decided to work on. Although I have declared my buttons (addButton, subtractButton, etc.) within the MainActivity.java file and have assigned them to their respective buttons within the XML file, I'm still receiving an error when I run my app. I believe this is because, within the OnClick method, the IDs for the view elements within the XML file are being recognized. For example, the ID of my '+' button is add_button in the XML, but when I try to write 
`case R.id.addButton`, I receive an error (but `case R.id.add_button` doesn't return an error).

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button addButton;
    Button subtractButton;
    Button multiplyButton;
    Button divideButton;
    TextView editText;
    EditText number1;
    EditText number2;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        addButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.add_button);
        multiplyButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.multiply_button);
        subtractButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.subtract_button);
        divideButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.divide_button);

        editText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.dispNum);
        number1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.num1);
        number2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.num2);


        addButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        multiplyButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        subtractButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        divideButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v){

        int num1=0,num2=0,result=0;

        num1=Integer.parseInt(number1.getText().toString());
        num2=Integer.parseInt(number2.getText().toString());

        switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.addButton:
                result=num1+num2;
                break;
            case R.id.subtract_button:
                result=num1-num2;
                break;
            case R.id.multiply_button:
                result=num1*num2;
                break;
            case R.id.divide_button:
                result=num1/num2;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        editText.setText(result);
    }
}
```

This is the XML file

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<EditText
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/num1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/num1"/>
<EditText
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/num2"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/num2"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="20dp">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="+"
        android:id="@+id/add_button"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="-"
        android:id="@+id/subtract_button"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="*"
        android:id="@+id/multiply_button"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="/"
        android:id="@+id/divide_button"/>
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="30dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="24dp"
    android:id="@+id/dispNum"/>
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is wrong ids you are getting into a switch case

look closely , in your xml the id of add button is "add_button" where as the case you are using for it is

```
case R.id.addButton:
```

so this is not the right and actual id of the add button . Please check twice further that you did not have messed up with ids.

Comment: you have to use the correct Id such as 
case  R.id.add_button

Answer (score 0):

in onClick you need to provide ids `add_button`you define in xml not that button variable you define in MainActivity which is `Addbutton`
this is not any issue this is how android onClick works.

Answer (score 0):

Check your onclick method you have used wrong id in switch case.
use `R.id.add_button` instead of `R.id.addButton`